# The specified field (price) could refer to more than one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

the specified field (price) could refer to more than one table  listed in the from clauses of your SQL statment. based in below,

```
SELECT Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, Orders.OrderDate, Products.ProductName, Products.Price, Products.BatchSize, [Price]*[BatchSize] AS [Full Price]
FROM Products INNER JOIN ((Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID)  ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Same with the field `BatchSize`.

You did not specify the name of the table when using the fields in the formula for `Full Price`, and if the title of your post should by any chance correspond to an error message that made you post your post, there is most probably also a field named `Price` in your `OrderDetails` table, so Access doesn't know which of the two fields to use when calculating the values (as you access both tables in your query). What you wanted to do was presumably the following:

```
SELECT Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, Orders.OrderDate, Products.ProductName,
  Products.Price, Products.BatchSize, Products.[Price]*Products.[BatchSize] AS [Full Price]
FROM Products INNER JOIN 
  ((Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) INNER JOIN 
    OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID)
  ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID;
```

**But:** If your `OrderDetails` table also contains a `Price`, please do not simply tell Access to use the field from the `Products` table but before ask yourself (or someone that knows the database structure) what table to specify (also for the 5th field in your query). Maybe the `Price` in the `Products` table is a *purchasing* price and the price that the customer has to pay is stored in the `OrderDetails` table (similar to the Northwind sample database).

Answer (score 0):

Specify the name of the table to use:

```
OrderDetails.[Price]*[BatchSize]
```

or:

```
Products.[Price]*[BatchSize]
```